# What kind of agave is this?

Tags: identification

I assumed that i had brought home a centuary plant but this looks different. It's grey apart from the edges that are painted in green. It's some sort of a varigated one but don't know which kind.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be Agave desmettiana 'silver Star', but  there are hundreds of variegated agaves of varying sizes - this link  https://www.plantdelights.com/apps/photo-gallery/agaves_-_variegated_cultivars shows many of them, including 'Silver Star' shown lower down.

Comment: Looks very similar to what i have here. Though i cant get much info on silver star on Google in terms of spacing, watering needs and so on. Also, i was wondering, since this is the first time im using agave in the landscape, can i pair it with other plants or am i limited to just grouping it with similar succulents alike? Those black phormiums would provide a really nice colour contrast paired with this.

Comment: Should be fine to plant Phormium - black mondo grass would be good too. Neither have high water requirements once established

Comment: As far as space, go by the average space of the A. desmeiiana that you can find information about.  I have one called Desert Sunset that is suppose to get about 1 metre tall and wide.